# Start content of sidebar at the left of centered-container

Tags: html, css, dom, layout, structure

Please see this Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vdb9y2m0/

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
<div class="container">
Testcontent in centered container
</div>
</div>
<div class="body">
<div class="sidebar">
Content (text) should start at header container
</div>
<div class="content">
Rest of the content, should end at header container
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 30%;
  background: #FFF;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.content {
  width: 70%;
  background: darkblue;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I would like to start the content of the left div in the body at the start of the container in the header - and end the div of the main content (darkblue) at the end of the container.

Like so:

[image: This should be the end result]

If this possible, without using some ugly Javascript hack? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/gxcapxkq/

Comment: Just make same container as top.. see https://jsfiddle.net/vdb9y2m0/2/

Comment: Ah, thanks! But the problem is that the background of the sidebar must start at the very left of the page. So that's only achievable by adding a 1px background or something?

Comment: check my fiddle. blue background start with the red border..that you want, right?